# Get a return code on executing hbase command in shell script

Tags: bash, unix, hbase

how to check the existence of `hbase` table using shell script:

```
if [HBASE COMMAND]
echo "table exist"
else
echo "create new table"
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

Exit status can be checked with `$?`, see [2.5.2 Special Parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)  from **The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7**:

```
printf "exists '%s'\n" mytable | hbase shell 2>&1 | grep -q "does exist" 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  printf "table exists\n"
else 
  printf "create new table\n"
fi
```

You can directly execute compound-list of commands with an `if` statement; see [The if Conditional Construct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07) section from **The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7**. If the exit status is 0 (success), the commands included in the `then` block are executed.

Give a try to this to check the existence of `mytable`:

```
if printf "exists '%s'\n" mytable | hbase shell 2>&1 | grep -q "does exist" 2>/dev/null ; then 
  printf "table exists\n"
else 
  printf "create new table\n"
fi
```

`grep -q` prints nothing to standard output, and the exit status is `0` (success) if the `regex` matches (if the string `does exist` is found in the output generated by `hbase` command).

`hbase shell -n` can be used to execute commands from a shell script.

Use the `exists` command to check the existence of a table.

Comment: getting this error while using this exists "LoadError: No such file to load -- -n
    load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1087"

Comment: oups, try to remove the `-n` (the answer has been updated). 

Is it better?